# What are the different studies on prime numbers like Ulam's square?

Tags: prime-numbers

I was writing a paper on prime numbers distribution. I am using graphical methods to show some observation about the nature of prime numbers. The article published by the Polish mathematician Stanislav Ulam is a mathematical note. Therefore my teacher said that it cannot be referred in the paper. I searched and searched online and could not find any study or paper related to this work. Can anyone please suggest some recent papers published on graphical study of prime numbers. Mathematical note by Stanislav ulam A Visual Display of Prime numbers distribution

Comment: You could try searching the web for "Ulam spiral" or "prime spiral". Maybe the references at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral will get you started.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks. I will look for them. I am truly desperate and not sure.

Comment: If you called it "Ulam spiral" instead of "Ulam square" you might find more appropriate references. For instance, look at the bibliography close to the bottom of this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSpiral.html

Comment: You'll let us know if you find anything useful, right, Vinay?

Comment: Are you still here, Vinay?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I am still looking at different places. There are no papers published but mathematical notes online.